# How to filter values of numpy ndarray based on a boolean mask?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy ndarray of shape (172,40,20) and a boolean mask of shape (172, 20). I can do it with a loop.

```
for i in range(172):
     filtered_values = array[i,:,mask[i]]
```

Is there any other way to do this without using loop?

Comment: `filtered_values = array[mask[:, np.newaxis]]`?

Comment: filtered_values might be different shaped across iterations. How do you plan to store those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a smaller 3d array that we can display, and play with:

```
In [2]: arr = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)                                                                   
In [3]: mask = np.ones((2,4),bool)                                                                           
In [4]: arr.shape                                                                                            
Out[4]: (2, 3, 4)
In [5]: mask.shape                                                                                           
Out[5]: (2, 4)

In [7]: for i in range(2): 
   ...:     print(arr[i,:,mask[i]]) 
   ...:                                                                                                      
[[ 0  4  8]
 [ 1  5  9]
 [ 2  6 10]
 [ 3  7 11]]
[[12 16 20]
 [13 17 21]
 [14 18 22]
 [15 19 23]]
```

This produces a (4,3) array; since it's mixing basic and advanced indexing, the slice dimension is put last.

Make it more interesting by setting some false elements:

```
In [8]: mask[0,[0,2]] = False                                                                                
In [9]: mask[1,[3]] = False                                                                                  
In [10]: mask                                                                                                
Out[10]: 
array([[False,  True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, False]])
In [11]: for i in range(2): 
    ...:     print(arr[i,:,mask[i]]) 
    ...:                                                                                                     
[[ 1  5  9]
 [ 3  7 11]]
[[12 16 20]
 [13 17 21]
 [14 18 22]]
```

We can't simply add the middle dimension (in earlier numpy this might have worked):

```
In [12]: arr[mask[:,None,:]]                                                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-cfdcce5848f0> in <module>
----> 1 arr[mask[:,None,:]]

IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1; dimension is 3 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1
```

We can use repeat to make a mask that matches `arr` in shape:

```
In [15]: mask[:,None].repeat(3,1)                                                                            
Out[15]: 
array([[[False,  True, False,  True],
        [False,  True, False,  True],
        [False,  True, False,  True]],

       [[ True,  True,  True, False],
        [ True,  True,  True, False],
        [ True,  True,  True, False]]])
In [16]: arr[mask[:,None].repeat(3,1)]                                                                       
Out[16]: array([ 1,  3,  5,  7,  9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22])
```

In general masking produces a 1d array.  To get 2d arrays I have to something like:

```
In [19]: arr[mask[:,None].repeat(3,1)][:6].reshape(3,2)                                                      
Out[19]: 
array([[ 1,  3],
       [ 5,  7],
       [ 9, 11]])
In [20]: arr[mask[:,None].repeat(3,1)][6:].reshape(3,3)                                                      
Out[20]: 
array([[12, 13, 14],
       [16, 17, 18],
       [20, 21, 22]])
```